# No sound when cast Google Photos to Chromecast using iPhone?

Tags: google, google-photos, chromecast

Problem: when I cast a video from Google Photos to Chromecast using my iPhone, I see that only the image of the video is cast to TV, the TV has no sound and the frame is lag, the sound remain on my iPhone, but if I press home on my iPhone, then the casting to my TV stopped.

Then I try using Google Photos on my friend's Samsung Android to cast a video, and it works perfectly.

I see that this problem exists since 2018, many has complained:

- [No sound when I cast videos from the Google Photos app to my TV,
  audio only plays from my phone.](https://support.google.com/chromecast/thread/799884?hl=en)
- [No sound when casting Google photos to tv. All other apps like Spotify and youtube works fine .](https://support.google.com/chromecast/thread/13440660?hl=en)
- [iOS Photos App, Cloud-Only Video to Chromecast (2&3): No Sound from TV, only iOS device](https://support.google.com/chromecast/thread/948504?hl=en)

This is the end of 2020 and it's still not fixed. So I don't expect Google will fix this on iPhone.

[Some user](https://support.google.com/chromecast/thread/948504?hl=en&msgid=948504) said

> When a local copy exists on iOS device, the picture quality on the TV
> is noticeably better than that of cloud-only videos. This suggests to
> me that the app is streaming the local version of the video, when
> available, directly from the iOS device to the Chromecast. When a
> local copy is not available, it's clearly using a different process to
> cast the cloud-only video, and that's where the issue is. While this
> may make perfect sense on an Android, Photos app for iOS is billed as
> a cloud service.

So beside having a local copy exists on iOS device, is there other way? Or I guess I'll just buy a Samsung Android to cast Google Photos video.

Comment: Still a problem halfway through 2022. Frustrating.

Comment: @RawwrBag : My current solution for Android TV, I use the app "Cloud Gallery" by "CJ Espinoza" to play Google Photos directly on my TV. app link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cjespinoza.cloudgallery